# How to consume a image from web service and showing it simply on a imageview in android?

Tags: android, image, web-services

Can any one tell me how to consume a image from web service, and tell me how to show that images in to the imageview control in android?

I have tried a lot of example through Google, but those are all not making me clear.

Can any one please give me atleast one sample to achieve this concept?

Thanks for your precious time!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the Image_URL from the API:

say for ex : http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jZgveEqb6pg/T3R4kXScycI/AAAAAAAAAE0/xQ7CvpfXDzc/s1024/sample_image_01.jpg

Pass this URL to the below function and you will get a Bitmap :

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;
InputStream in = null;
BufferedOutputStream out = null;

try {
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

    final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
    copy(in, out);
    out.flush();

    final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //options.inSampleSize = 1;

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
} finally {
    closeStream(in);
    closeStream(out);
}

return bitmap;
```

}

and you can set  image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Hope this can help you.

Note : If you want to load a list of images use lazy loader.

Answer (score 0):

you can consume the image from webserver by using the url of the image which is stored in server....

Answer (score 0):

What type of web service are you using?

If you are using KSOAP you can use like this.

```
          try 
           {

                ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

              final String encodedImage = response.toString();

      byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

      decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

      yourimgView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);

            catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

android default `ImgaeView` does not support http URI.. You can use [this third party lib](https://github.com/tom-dignan/android-remoteimageview)`RemoteImagView` which suports http URI for the image url....

Answer (score 0):

Check the response of your webservice, there you can find image URL, grab that url and pass it to the image view object. You will get proper response of you question if you post your webservice response.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever webserverice is used soap or json you have to get the url.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detailImageView);

if(urlToDownload!=null)
{
URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);//url of image to download.
url.openConnection().setConnectTimeout(1000);
bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```